# Creating a unique listing_no (Java/PostgreSQL)

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, random

I am working on a option in a Menu function that posts the car for the sale in a database. The option asks for the user to enter the year, make, condition and price, which is then inserted into the table car_sale in the database. However, a unique listing_no must also be generated during this option. I cannot define my tables to uniquely generate the 10 digit number the option but I must code the program to insert uniquely generated listing_no. Below you will find the code of me trying to do this, however the code only works in Oracle but I cannot use Oracle.  I can only PostGreSQL and Java. Therefore, my problem arises as the functions and relations I am using cannot be used in PostGre.

Code to Generate Listing No:

```
 public int generateListingNo() throws SQLException
 {
  int listingSeq = 0;
  Statement select = connection.createStatement();
  result = select.executeQuery("select (to_char(sysdate,'yyyymmdd')||AUDIT_SEQ.NEXTVAL)valnext from dual");;
  if(result.next())
  {
     listingSeq = result.getInt(1);
  }

  int seq = listingSeq;

  return seq;
 }
```

Code in The Option Function to insert the lisitng_no generated from generateListingNo()

```
public void option() throws SQLException
   {
int listing_no = generateListingNo();
         // insert information into books_for_sale table
         sql_insert = "INSERT INTO car_sale VALUES(" + listing_no +", "
                       + "'" + year + "'" + ", " +
                       "'" + make + "'" +", " +
                       "'" + condition + "'" + ", "
                       + price + ")";
```

Erros I am Getting:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "dual" does not exist
  Position: 69 at 
      org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:217)
           at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:421)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:318)
           at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeQuery(PgStatement.java:281)
```

Creating the car_sale table

```
create table car_sale(
listing_no int not null,
year varchar not null,
make varchar not null,
condition varchar not null,
price decimal(12,2) not null,
primary key (listing_no),
```

Comment: What is the error  u get .

Comment: @RehanAzher I have edited the error in my question. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can u also post the create statement of your table? Doesn't looks like an issue with your code.

Comment: @RehanAzher I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Change you query for generateListingNo as below:

```
select   q from (select (to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd') || NEXTVAL('AUDIT_SEQ') )q )sq
```

or

```
select (to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd') || NEXTVAL('AUDIT_SEQ')) as newseqval
```

or on your cocde:

```
public int generateListingNo() throws SQLException
 {
  int listingSeq = 0;
  Statement select = connection.createStatement();
  result = select.executeQuery("select (to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd') || NEXTVAL('AUDIT_SEQ')) as newseqval");;
  if(result.next())
  {
     listingSeq = result.getInt(1);
  }

  int seq = listingSeq;

  return seq;
 }
```

Since you dont have sequence :

Either create sequence using below query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public."AUDIT_SEQ"
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;
```

or use UUID:

```
public String generateListingNo() throws SQLException
     {
       return UUID.randomUUID().toString();     
     }
```

your table structure will need to change :

```
create table car_sale(
listing_no varchar not null,
year varchar not null,
make varchar not null,
condition varchar not null,
price decimal(12,2) not null,
primary key (listing_no),
```

Comment: Please  Make Sure you have set the starting value of Seq to be more than 2 digits. Also, I recommend not use INT but BigInt in case your record will grow more than 10 digits.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work. I am getting the error audit_seq does not exist

Comment: Can u try to print the value of listseq in if block.

Comment: It won't allow me because of the error of 'audit_seq relation does not exist'. Can I use this in PostGreSQL?

Comment: Yes i have tested this in PG, please check if u have created the  sequence or not.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Does the sequence AUDIT_SEQ exist in your schema?

Comment: You can use this query to  create sequence:

`CREATE SEQUENCE public."AUDIT_SEQ"
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    CACHE 1;`

Comment: No, it doesn't but is there any other way to generate automatic listing_no just in the program when the option is selected?

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, you have to call query this way from java :

```
SELECT nextval('ACCOUNT_TRANSACTION_NO')
```

Comment: OP is trying to concatenate a date to make it 10 digits. problem is DUAL

Comment: dual is not used in postgresql